# How to synchronize http.get requests in Angular, when the second request depends on the first one?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to perform a sequence of http requests to my database from Angular. In the first step I get an array of objects. This is working fine. 
In a second step I want to populate each object with additional data. So I need to wait for the first http.request to complete. *I also don't want to return before my data has been fetched.*

My function getData() should return an Observable, because the interface / signature is not supposed to change (as it is being used in other parts of the program and an observable makes sense for the program logic).

```
// Returns an array with objects, that have an id, that is needed for the second call 

data[] : Object = new Array(); 
populatedData[] : Object = new Array();


getData(): Observable<Object[]>{
  this.http.get<Object[]>("http://localhost:3000/data").subscribe(data => this.data = data);

// This needs the data from the first call 
 for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
this.http.get<Object>("http://localhost:3000/data/"+data[i].id).subscribe(data => populatedData.push(data)); 
}


return of(populatedData); 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promise is an option but another option can be,

```
// Returns an array with objects, that have an id, that is needed for the second call 
   data[] : Object = new Array(); 
   populatedData[] : Object = new Array();

  getData(): Observable<Object[]>{
     this.http.get<Object[]>("http://localhost:3000/data").subscribe((data)=>{
      this.data = data;
             for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                  this.http.get<Object>("http://localhost:3000/data/"+data[i].id).subscribe((response)=> {
                          populatedData.push(response)
                   }); 
             }
         });
      return of(populatedData); 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `switchMap` (after the initial GET is done, make the other requests) and `forkJoin` (make several requests and emit when all are completed). Something like this:

```
    getSingleEntry = ({ id }) => this.http.get<Object[]>("http://localhost:3000/data/" + id);

    getData = () => this.http.get<Object[]>("http://localhost:3000/data")
        .pipe(
            tap(data => this.data = data),
            switchMap(data => forkJoin(data.map(this.getSingleEntry)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code that needs the first call in the second

```
data: Array<any> = []; 
populatedData: Array<any> = []; 



getData(): Observable<Object[]> {
    this.http.get<Object[]>('http://localhost:3000/data').subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            this.http
                .get<Object>('http://localhost:3000/data/' + data[i].id)
                .subscribe(data => populatedData.push(data));
        }
    });

    return of(populatedData);
}
```

Comment: The return type of an asynchronous function has to be a Promise.

Comment: The observable `getData` is returning is resolved even before the first request is completed, let alone the last.

Comment: No. It should emit after the requests are completed, not before they are sent. The subscriber of `getData` will - immediately - receive an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best idea is to use `switchMap` RXJS operator and `zip`. In second calls you have access to data from first one. Then you can return array of values when all calls are done.

More about `switchMap` you can read [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html). About `zip` [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html).

Here you have example how data will looks like https://rxviz.com/v/Mogdv96O

Then your code will be refactored as follow:

```
  getData(): Observable<Object[]> {
    this.http.get<Object[]>("http://localhost:3000/data")
      .pipe(switchMap((data) =>
              zip(...data.map(item => this.http.get<Object>("http://localhost:3000/data/" + item.id)))
            )
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the error occurs when the Windows Features are not set up corretly.
You have to enter the -> 'Turn Windows features on or off' from the Windows Search and enter toggle 'HTTP Activation' and is presented on the picture:
[Options to toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06RPd.png)